# Calculating correct eigenvectors in R to find the eigendecomposition

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Im not sure how to write code properly in stack overflow so i will try. I want to compute the exact Eigenvectors on R but the eigen() function is giving me strange answers. my problem is:

```
A<-matrix(1,nrow=3,ncol=3)

eigen(A)

$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.5773503  0.8164966  0.0000000
[2,] -0.5773503 -0.4082483 -0.7071068
[3,] -0.5773503 -0.4082483  0.7071068
```

now my goal is to find the eigen decomposition of A which is $A=vdv^t$ where v is an orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors and d is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues along the diagonal. Now the matrix of eigenvectors found above is not Orthogonal as

```
f<-eigen(A)
V<-f$vectors
V
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.5773503  0.8164966  0.0000000
[2,] -0.5773503 -0.4082483 -0.7071068
[3,] -0.5773503 -0.4082483  0.7071068

 V %*% t(V)
             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,] 1.000000e+00  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
[2,] 5.551115e-17  1.000000e+00 -2.220446e-16
[3,] 5.551115e-17 -2.220446e-16  1.000000e+00
```

An orthogonal matrix multiplied by its transpose should equal the identity matrix. Now i know that if i where to
`zapsmall(V%*%t(V))`

It would equal the identity matrix but I am looking to find the matrix of eigenvectors that is already orthogonal. Im not sure if my understanding of the topic is wrong or I am calculating something wrong.

Comment: So the problem is that "5.551115e-17" isn't close enough to zero for your needs? Most computer languages work with floating point numbers which have limits to precision. There's a big gap between theoretical values and values that a computer can easily calculate.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem as the algorithm that I am using requires orthogonality to converge. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Essentially another variant of the [famous R FAQ Question 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and the references therein.

Comment: Well, you already found `zapsmall`. As to what affect that would have on your algorithm, it's not really possible to say without more details. The algorithm needs to be written with an understanding of the limitations of floating point arithmetic in mind.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I will try and incorporate this into my algorithm and look into floating point numbers.

Comment: Is there possibly a function in R that finds the closest orthogonal matrix to a given matrix?